# Error using S4G Currency updater app for automatically updating currency exchange rates

Tags: opportunity, multi-currency

I have multi-currency enabled org where I am using [S4G currency updater](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000025GWyEAM&revId=a0S3000000Hp1DgEAJ&tab=r), which automatically updates currency rates using yahoo's webservice. 
I have also enabled Advanced Currency Management (Dated Exchanged Rate). 
Right now I have 6 currencies enable including the corporate currency (which is USD) with appropriate exchange rates. The rates are positive. (e.g. 1 USD = 1.31 AUD)

I have 3 use cases where I am getting errors

**Usecase 1:** When I run the currency updater with "Use Advanced Currency Management" checkbox checked, I get following error in the logs.

```
Starting Currency Updater: 2015-03-17 12:56:42
GBP can't be update on SF. ERROR: The conversion rate has to be positive
CAD can't be update on SF. ERROR: The conversion rate has to be positive
EUR can't be update on SF. ERROR: The conversion rate has to be positive
AUD can't be update on SF. ERROR: The conversion rate has to be positive
CHF can't be update on SF. ERROR: Unexpected character ('E' (code 69)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:2, column:2]
Ending Currency Updater: 2015-03-17 13:00:47
```

**Usecase 2:** When I uncheck the "Use Advance Currency Management" checkbox and run the currency updater again I get a different error as follows:

```
Starting Currency Updater: 2015-03-17 13:13:05
GBP can't be update on SF. ERROR: Required fields are missing: [ConversionRate]
CAD can't be update on SF. ERROR: Required fields are missing: [ConversionRate]
EUR can't be update on SF. ERROR: Required fields are missing: [ConversionRate]
AUD can't be update on SF. ERROR: Required fields are missing: [ConversionRate]
CHF can't be update on SF. ERROR: Unexpected character ('E' (code 69)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:2, column:2]
Ending Currency Updater: 2015-03-17 13:15:55
```

**Usecase 3:** When I disable Dated Exchange Rates and run the currency updater with/without "Use Advance Currency Management" I get following error:

```
Starting Currency Updater: 2015-03-17 14:44:07
GBP can't be update on SF. ERROR: entity type cannot be inserted: Dated Conversion Rate
CAD can't be update on SF. ERROR: entity type cannot be inserted: Dated Conversion Rate
EUR can't be update on SF. ERROR: entity type cannot be inserted: Dated Conversion Rate
AUD can't be update on SF. ERROR: entity type cannot be inserted: Dated Conversion Rate
Ending Currency Updater: 2015-03-17 14:46:33
```

I am totally lost while debugging this issue. I have also contacted S4G support for this issue but haven't got any reply. 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Try with the last version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this response from S4G to another user on the review page in the AppExchange:

[Javier Heitz] Hi Donovan / Puneet, Thanks for your patience. Unfortunately, we have been a bit swamped with complaints about this error. The reason: Yahoo Finance changed their serialization and broke our development. We have now managet to fix it in version 3.6 so if you uninstall and reinstall again it should work Ok. Regards

Hope this helps. BTW, other than this issue, have you found the app useful? I'm investigating using multi currency right now for our ORG and was reviewing the free apps out there for auto updating

Answer (score 0):

With the last versión of S4G Currency Updater, it is solved. The problem was that Yahoo changes the response schema.